# How to call 3rd party Erlang module from Elixir?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I have an Elixir project that uses mix. I already use some built-in erlang modules, but now I need to use a third party module I found on Github.

How do I import, build and call a third party Erlang module from Elixir?

EDIT: The module I am interested in right now is located at https://github.com/aggelgian/erlang-algorithms , specifically, the `edmonds_karp` module.

Comment: Does that module use `rebar`? Can you give us the URL of that repo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding third-party erlang packages is quite easy in elixir. If the package isn't on Hex.pm, then you can just use the github url. E.g. in `mix.exs`:

```
defp deps do
  [
    {:erlang_algorithms, github: 'aggelgian/erlang-algorithms'},
  ]
end
```

Then you can just run `mix deps.get`

However in your case this will fail because the package doesn't have an app file. To fix this change the above to be:

```
  defp deps do
    [
      {:erlang_algorithms, github: 'aggelgian/erlang-algorithms', app: false},
    ]
  end
```

Then again run `mix deps.get`.

Now you can access the erlang modules available in the package:

E.g.

```
:dfs.run(arg1, arg2)
```